# Can I make a window always stay in the background?

Tags: focus

I'm using `xpad` for sticky notes, but I don't really like, that they appear on only one workspace by default, so I set it to show up on all. But with this setting, when I click a note, it comes above all the windows in all the workspaces. I thought it would be perfect, if I could make xpad keep in the background like conky. Is this achievable? I don't mind, if I have to set it manually every time I start xpad.

Answers specific to xpad are welcome, but I'd be happier for a general solution that would work with any application.

Comment: I have the same problem with plasma-desktop

Answer (score 0):

In xfce (I'm using Xubuntu) you can simply right click bar on top of the window and choose "keep on background" (or something like that, I don't use english version of my system).

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case in Unity, or Gnome. I only have an option to keep on top. That's exactly the feature I'm missing, and for which I search an alternative available in Unity. However your answer might be useful for future xfce using visitors.

Comment: It has been added

Comment: What could a developer do to do that automatically in the program code?